# Animal Crossing New Leaf: Data transfering

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Awhile back I bought myself a 3ds so that I can play animal crossing new leaf. I've had the same ds for over three years now and recently I decided it's time for a new one being that its really beaten up. So i purchased the animal crossing 3ds xl. Being that i have gotten so far into the game i have been wondering if i can transfer the data from my normal game, to the pre downloaded one on my new ds. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. Take a look at the [Save Data Transfer Tool](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Nintendo-3DS-2DS/Usage-/Save-Data-Transfer-Tool/What-is-the-Save-Data-Transfer-Tool-/What-is-the-Save-Data-Transfer-Tool--740818.html). This way, you can transfer save data from the game cart to the digital game on your system. Notice you can't transfer the data back from the digital game to your game card.

Comment: You could transfer the data back from the digital game to the card game with [this](https://gbatemp.net/threads/save-data-manager-and-editor-for-firmware-up-to-9-9.396245/)